# I want to truncate address line 2 to 10 characters

Tags: apache-flex

I want to truncate address line 2 to 10 characters if a value greater than 10 characters is returned in the address validation response for address line 2. we also have address line 1 which is set to max of 40 characters, if address line 1 exceeds 40 characters and the result comes to address line 2,and if the length for address line 2 reaches more than 10 characters then i need to truncate that to 10 characters. hope i made it clear. can any one give an example for that.

Thanks
Lucky

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Flex?

Comment: Flex.Just need an idea about how to implement it

Comment: *"can any one gimme.."*  I can give you some basic advice.  Not all people on SO speak English as a native language, so avoid immature slang terms like 'gimme'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
valueYouWantToTrucante.substr(0,10);
```

[More info on the substr method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substr%28%29).

If sounds like you only want to do this if some condition is true; did you also need help writing that condition?

---

Since @Lucky asked for help w/ the condition.  This is psuedo code:

```
if((address1Text.length > 40) && (address2ValidationResult.length > 10)){
    valueYouWantToTrucante.substr(0,10);
}
```

Comment: Yes if you can help me in that too..these are my baby steps towards programming.

Comment: @Lucky I gave it a shot; but it is in psuedo code.  The way you describe what you want to do is a bit confusing.